# How to dispaly an image when grabbing data from webservice

Tags: c#, wpf, web-services

May i know how to add an image when my WPF application is grabbing data from the web service? Since my application need some moment to grab the data and insert it into the datagrid, so i think its reasonable to display an image or notification to inform the user that my program is running. Any advice? Thanks

C# code snippet for data grabbing:

```
private void search_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyData.WebService myApi = new MyData.WebService();
        var dbs = myApi.GetDealerInfoByID(0); //select data start from the ID:0

        var i = from p in dbs.Product
                select new
                {
                    Name = p.ProductName,
                    Price = p.ProductPrice,                     
                };

        myDataGrid.ItemsSource = i;
    }
```

Comment: So to infom user that data is loading is good you can make use of `BusyIndicator` control which is available in toolkit. Here is tutorial of it how to use it : [WPF BusyIndicator Control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/wpf-busyindicator/)

Comment: you may shown Image  "Getting Data ,Please Wait". after MyData.WebService myApi = new MyData.WebService();

and hide it after last line of event.

Comment: where is this control????

Comment: you can download a png that's having some animation over it and display till you fetch the data

Comment: looking a long way around !!! rather can display some animated png

Comment: @Prasad - its part of toolkit check tutorial link given over here

Comment: Displaying any kind of busy indicator will only work when you [asynchronously call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tz4bkcx2%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) the web service. In your code, as soon as you call `GetDealerInfoByID` the UI gets frozen until the method has completed.

Comment: so you better need to add a worker thread to do this task in parallel

Comment: i had tried two approaches...the 1st one is the MessageBox.show after  MyData.WebService myApi = new MyData.WebService();. However, the MessageBox will halt all the processes until the MessageBox is closed. The 2nd apporach i tried is i set the visibility of "Loading" text to visible when the application is grabbing the data. However, as what @Clemens mention, the UI will get frozen and the effect of the "Loading" text can't be seen.......Any more advice?